# Problema com alert

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, materialize

Boa tarde,

Estou começando com Javascript/JQuery estou com algum problema no alert do meu projeto.
Pode ser um problema de lógica, mas por eu estar começando, não estou conseguindo enxergar onde está o erro.
É um gerador de botões Bootstrap, onde o usuário insere o textoe a cor do botão, ao clicar em "Gerar" o botão é adicionado. Entretanto, gostaria de colocar um alert com o conteúdo do texto a cada botão clicado gerado.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css"> -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 teal white-text center">
      <h1>Criador de Botões</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="input-field col s5"><input type="text" placeholder="Texto do botão" id="inp-text"></div>
      <div class="input-field col s5">

        <select id="sel-color">
          <option value="teal">Teal</option>
          <option value="blue">Blue</option>
          <option value="green">Green</option>
          <option value="pink">Pink</option>
          <option value="black">Black</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col s2">
        <button class="btn teal" id="btn-create">CRIAR</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="container" id="container">
      <div class="col s4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popular.js"></script> -->
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('select').formSelect();

      $('#btn-create').click(function () {
        texto = $('#inp-text').val();
        cor = $('#sel-color').val();
        $('#container').append('<button class="btn ' + cor + '">' + texto + '</button> ');
        $('#container > button').click(function () {
          alert($(this).text());
        });
      });

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Porém ao clicar nos botões criados, os alerts se repetem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
$('#container > button').click(function () {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Ao fazer a chamada desse método, você está criando um *event listener* em todos os botões que são filhos do `#container`.

Como esse método é chamado múltiplas vezes, você está criando múltiplos *event listeners* para os mesmos elementos.

Tente dessa forma:

```
$('#btn-create').click(function () {
  const texto = $('#inp-text').val();
  const cor = $('#sel-color').val();
  const botao = $('<button class="btn ' + cor + '">' + texto + '</button>');

  $('#container').append(botao);
  botao.click(function () {
    alert($(this).text());
  });  
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Resolveu meu problema e o código ficou bem melhor. Vou estudar a respeito de event listeners.